# Unable to create dynamic sql query in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am keep getting

***Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '46434,15864' to data type int.***

I have this texbox which accepts numeric and commas. I need to create query with emp_num in (46434,15864) like syntax.

[image]

The query generated from codebehind is this, which runs fine manually in sql server:

```
SELECT   *  -- column names
FROM [DBO].[tablename] LPR 
WHERE LPR.[EMPLOYEE_NUMBER] in (46434,15864)
```

code:

```
  if (txtEmpNum.Text.Trim() != "")
        {
            ////sb.Append("  and LPR.[EMPLOYEE_NUMBER] like '%'+ @empnumber + '%' ");  
            sb.Append("  and LPR.[EMPLOYEE_NUMBER] in (@empnumber) ");  
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@empnumber", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtEmpNum.Text.Trim(); //.Replace("," ,  "','");
        }

        cmd.CommandText = sb.ToString();

        DataTable dt = GetData(cmd);
        gvdetails.DataSource = dt;
        gvdetails.DataBind();
```

Table:
[image]

Comment: you have to remove ','

Comment: but from where, the input field ?

Comment: Your in statement is wrong with dynamic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to parametrize every value. This way you'll have dynamically created query, but NOT prone to SQL Inject
Here's code:

```
//where IN part of your query
string inClause = "and LPR.[EMPLOYEE_NUMBER] in ({0})";
// string arrays for values and variables of your query
string[] paramValues = txtEmpNum.Text.Trim().Split(',');
string[] paramVars = paramValues.Select((s, i) => "@empNo" + i.ToString()).ToArray();

//create query, ie. and LPR.[EMPLOYEE_NUMBER] in (@empNo0, @empNo1...)
inClause = string.Format(inClause, string.Join(", ", paramVars));

//add vars and values to command
for (int i = 0; i < paramVars.Length; i++)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramVars[i], SqlDbType.Int).Value = paramValues[i];
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution! Thanks a lot Nino.

Comment: Just curious why it was not working. Reason I am asking because the query generated in stringbuilder runs fine on sql server editor window but not here ?

Comment: by adding parameter with `Parameters.Add`, because of it's type (`VarChar`), your parameter gets enclosed with single qoutes and it becomes `LPR.[EMPLOYEE_NUMBER] in ('46434,15864')`

Answer (score 2):

You need a split function to create a list from an string. You can create that function running this script once :

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] 
( 
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX) 
) 
BEGIN 
    set @delimiter = coalesce(@delimiter, dbo.cSeparador());

    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO @output (splitdata)  
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)

    END 
    RETURN 
END
```

Now your query will be :

```
SELECT *
FROM [DBO].[tablename] LPR 
WHERE LPR.[EMPLOYEE_NUMBER] in (select * from fnSplitString(@empnumber, ','))
```

You can call it from C# exactly the same way you called your original code.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to split the input of the textbox and then add it as two separate int parameters? That way it is not vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Comment: Yes, but would two parameters be enough ?. Aren't there cases when the users will try to check three or four codes ?.

Comment: Well then split it, then iterate through all the parts. A bit more complicated but at least it leads to safer code.

Comment: Yes, you can use a split function, and use it on your select. I will edit my answer to show it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the error is saying that your variable `@empnumber` is `varchar` and `LPR.[EMPLOYEE_NUMBER]` is integer

You can just append the value of your textbox to your query.

***Edit:*** As others have suggested, this would be prone to SQL Injection. Marc Guillot and Nino solutions are better.